# PhpChart as flat image

Tags: php, pdf

Is there a way to generate a flat image of my graph made with PhpChart in Php?

I know I can get the image in javascript using $(this).jqplotToImageElem(); but this doesn't help as I need to be able to put it into a PDF document I am creating in Php. I have tried using ajax to save the file to the server but the request URI is too long, so I really just need to generate the flat image in Php.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would write what work around I did for this in case anyone has the same issue. I created a POST form with a hidden input and once the page with the chart on it was loaded I used jQuery to put `$(this).jqplotToImageElem().src;` into the value of that input and then submit the form to the page needing the image. The receiving page can then use `<img src="<?php $_POST['imagesrc'] ?>" />` to show the flat image of the chart, in my case I used the src in my pdf document.